# Play YouTubePlayer programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API to play a video in my app.

I want to play the video right when the user enters the fragment so I used the command `player.play();` in order to play automatically. However this command doesn't seem to work...

Here is my code:

```
public class YouTubeVideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment{

YouTubePlayer player;

public YouTubeVideoFragment()
{
}


@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(player!= null)
    {
        player.release();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if(player!= null)
    {
        player.release();
    }
}

public static YouTubeVideoFragment newInstance(String url)
{

    YouTubeVideoFragment f = new YouTubeVideoFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("url", url);

    f.setArguments(b);
    f.init();

    return f;
}

private void init()
{

    initialize("api_key", new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1)
        {

            Log.e("YouTubeFragment", "Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
        {



            if (!wasRestored)
            {
                player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                player.play();//THIS DOESNT WORK!!!

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

If you need to load and play a video right after initialization of a fragment, you should simply use `player.loadVideo(videoId)` instead of `player.cueVideo(videoId)` and override `onLoaded()` hook.

Have a look at the docs:

> *loadVideo(String videoId)*
>   **Loads and plays** the specified video.
>
> *cueVideo(String videoId)*
>   Loads the specified video's thumbnail and **prepares the player to play the video, but does not download** any of the video stream until play() is called.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call player.play() in onLoaded() of PlayerStateChangeListener().
So change onInitializationSuccess to this:

```
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
    {
        if (!wasRestored)
        {
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
                player.play();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorReason reason) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
            }
        });
     }
```